# Page background color and margins in SSRS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to change the background color of the entire page in an SSRS report? I tried changing the background color of the body. It works, but I still get a white background in the part that corresponds to the margin area.

See image below.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

[image]

EDIT:

Well :P, it's not really obvious but there is a white section around the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin area is "outside" the report and therefore you can't set properties on them such as colour. You can try setting the margin size to zero and adjusting the layout of the report so that the report items are not right at the edge of the body (which will now take up the whole page). This may work for you, it depends on the kind of output that is intended for the report  - for example I'm not sure printers will be able to print a page with no margin, so you might still see some margin on printed output even when zero is specified. Online or embedded reports should look ok though.